# Android TicTacToe best layout to use

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android programing. 
I'm trying to create the famous game "tictactoe". Do you know what layout should I use to put this image as game board ?

[image: GameBoard]

I want the game to be something like this

[image]

I've tried to use the gridlayout but I can't put the ball or circle images inside the gridlayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a framelayout as parent with your background image, then you should calculate the position of the views ( circle or x) and add to your layout.

Comment: How do I adjust the image to a certain x or y value on the framelayout ? I could insert the image the layout but then I couldn't move to the desired position

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do a game, the better way is use Unity 3d, if you want an android app too its posible but with a lower performance.
In your case, you must use 3 frame layout in a linear layout(horizontal), repeat this 3 times, a linear layout(vertical) containts the 3 linear layouts(horizontal).